# copy to existing file throw error if non existant java

Tags: java, file-io, error-handling

I am trying to write a method that takes in a file, and copies it to another. This should throw back an error if the destination file does not exist. I've got my code here.

```
    public static void takeAndCopyFile(String sourceFile, String destinationFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

    try {
        File inFile = new File(sourceFile);
        File outFile = new File(destinationFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        if (outFile.exists()){

            while ((length = fin.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                fout.write(buffer,0,length);
            }
        }
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found!");
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        fout.close();
        fin.close();
    }
```

What is confusing to me is how the if statement is clearly false if I pass a non-existant file name and it should go on the the FileNotFoundException.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: *"I pass a non-existant file name and it should go on the the FileNotFoundException."* - why? `FFNE` would relate to `sourceFile` not the `destinationFile`, as you can write to either (and exist or non-exist) file - assuming the path is correct

Answer (score 0):

If the `if` condition is not meet, no exception will be thrown, the `if` statement's body won't be executed.

If you want to throw an exception in that case, you'll have to explicitly do that, something like:

```
if(outFile.exists()){
     ...
}else{
   throw new FileNotFoundException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> how the if statement is clearly false if I pass a non-existant file name and it should go on the the FileNotFoundException

No, [`exists`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()) won't throw `FileNotFoundException` exception, because its purpose is to test if exists or not. To avoid such exception later.

*Tests whether the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname exists.*

Answer (score 0):

Simple plain java 7+

```
 Files.copy(Paths.get(filePath), Paths.get(filePath));
```

If the destination does not exist you get

> Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: